# An algorithm to convert an integer number to another type which just has letters 1...9 and a...z

Tags: android

In an Android application,

I need an algorithm to convert an integer number to another type which just has the following letters:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   a   b   c   ...  s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
```

Example of converted integer:

```
1  => 1  
34 => y  
35 => z  
36 (which is 35 + 1) => 11   
37 (which is 35 + 2) => 12  
1261 (which is 35 x 35 + 35 + 1) => 111  
1262 (which is 35 x 35 + 35 + 2) => 112   
...
```

The use of this algorithm is reducing the length of the integer digits

**Question:**
With what algorithm I can reach to this goal?

Comment: So you're wanting to convert base 10 into base 36?

Comment: yes base 10 into base 36 but no zero there

Comment: I guess technically it's base 35 I think. What language are you using? Most likely have a method for converting for you.

Comment: Android Studio (Java)

Comment: 111 = Integer.toString(1261, 35)

Comment: yet zero is there but there is no problem, I can accept this as true answer

Comment: @Phaelaxz: 10 = Integer.toString(35, 35); oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modified version of base conversion (to handle the missing 0):

```
String conv( int n ) {
    String map = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String c = "";
    while ( n > 0 ) {
        n -= 1;
        c = map.charAt(n%35) + c; 
        n = n / 35;
    }
    return c;
}
```